# Buddypress User Settings template location?

Tags: themes, buddypress

I am trying to customize my BuddyPress layout and I can't find where to edit the user profile page layout.

EG: /members/username-nice/settings/

This is just the page where you can change your password. The header and footer appear as they should, and there's a form to change your password, but I can't find the template file where this is coming from.

I've copied all the files from from /wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-themes/bp-default/members/single over to my theme. There is ** NO ** settings folder within this folder.

I was able to edit all the other profile templates (activity, profile, etc) because these templates were there in the theme.

1) where/do these files exist?

2) is this content being generated by WP and not BP? If so, which default template is is falling back on? And how do I edit around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED ....

The settings tab is rendered through the template

```
members/single/plugins.php
```